# delete table with links

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got this table in `MySQL Database`:

- `country`
- `country_province`
- `country_province_municipality`
- `country_province_municipality_barangay`

Here's the the `Foreign Keys` for each table:

- `country.objid` link to `country_province.countryid`
- `country_province.objid` link to `country_province_municipality.provinceid`
- `country_province_municipality.objid` link to `country_province_municipality_barangay.municipalityid`

So, the **4 tables** are connected by each other by its `objid`.

**QUESTION:** I was about to delete the links of all the records of 4 tables using the `country.objid` only. How to do it?

The script should look something like this:

```
delete country, country_province, country_province_municipality, country_province_municipality_barangay where country.objid = 'country0001'
```

Comment: Give "on delete cascade for foreignkey "...http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: how about without using DELETE CASDADE?

Answer (score 0):

Give "on delete cascade" for your foreignkeys.

MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE referential action for a foreign key to delete data from child tables when you delete data from a parent table.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: how about without using DELETE CASCADE?